# ADD class to all my images (thumbail)

Tags: images, thumbnails

I have a xxx web like xvideos for example.
And I want to add a class to my thumbail images because I want to indicate that the pop up add only will active when they click in these images.

So, i have tried to add with the plugin woody snippets these codes:

1:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
  the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('class' => 'alignleft'));
}
```

2:

```
function add_image_class($class){
    $class .= ' additional-class';
    return $class;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class','add_image_class');
```

But they dont work, and at moment I dont find how to give to all my images one CLASS. Somebody can help me

Comment: Where did you add that filter?

Comment: Using the pluging, they have an option to add codes in html ,js, php, etc

Comment: try adding those code into your currently active theme's functions.php file

Comment: which of the two?

Comment: I almost try:  $(function(){
    $('img').addClass('posts');
}); But it did not work. I am done :c

Comment: function add_image_class($class){ $class .= ' additional-class'; return $class; } add_filter('get_image_tag_class','add_image_class');

Comment: I am adding this: function add_image_class($class){ $class .= ' FOTOS'; return $class; } add_filter('get_image_tag_class','add_image_class'); where my class name is FOTOS. But it does not work.

Comment: Are you checking on already added image? It's working for those images which will be added once you add this code to functions.php file

Comment: Yes, I want for images that I already uploaded. How i can do that?

Comment: I just have tried with a new image, but it did not work... I think I am doing something bad!! But I dont know what. I am uploading the image and it appear in the Media. And I am using that image

Comment: function add_responsive_class($content){

        $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
        $document = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $document->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content));

        $imgs = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach ($imgs as $img) {
           $img->setAttribute('class','FOTOS');
        }

        $html = $document->saveHTML();
        return $html;
}add_filter('the_content', 'add_responsive_class');

Comment: try this in functions.php file.

Comment: Dont work :( For already uploaded images and for new images

Comment: What could be happen?

Comment: function add_custom_class_to_all_images($content){
   
    $my_custom_class = "FOTOS1"; // your custom class
    $add_class = str_replace('<img class="', '<img class="'.$my_custom_class.' ', $content); // add class
    return $add_class; // display class to image
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_custom_class_to_all_images');

Comment: Hello! I found the solution! I inspected my website and i check that all my thumbails has many many class from my theme.(category, and other things) And one of them is has-post-thumbail. I use that CLASS and the pop up works for all my images :D

Comment: very thanks bro! I need to learn a lot of html and javascript

Comment: And for try to do this all this night, I have this problem: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/350557/what-does-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in-mean

Comment: Okey so you didn't tried above code?

Comment: The last code that you gave me not. I am worried, if my solution works and dont want to touch it jeje