# What does "Trying to get property of non object in.." mean?

Tags: themes

I was moving something in my web to add a class to all my images, and now i have this message:

[15-Oct-2019 10:44:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /home/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 825

[15-Oct-2019 10:44:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /home/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 825

[15-Oct-2019 10:44:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /home/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 829

What could be happen? I have made rollback but the message still appear. Is it dangerous?

Comment: Can you share with us the code referenced by those warnings?

Comment: This is exactly the message:
[15-Oct-2019 10:44:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /home/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 825
[15-Oct-2019 10:44:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /home/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 825
[15-Oct-2019 10:44:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /home/public_html/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 829

Comment: It sounds like further up the stack trace something is calling `wp_nav_menu`, however, line 825 of `nav-menu.php` doesn't reference `post_title`, it's a check for trashed values. Have you modified WP Core files in `wp-includes? https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L825

Comment: I dont modify nothing. I just add code in my theme, I have an section to add Javascript Code. And I download the plugin Woody - Insert Header, footer. To add the code there too. But in WP-CORE or WP-includes. Nothing.

Comment: Do you think I should contact with my host and make roll-back from yesterday?

Comment: Can you verify that by installing WP over the top of your existing install so that the files in `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` are known to match the official release? Also can you confirm you're up to date and not using an ancient version of WP? Also, what exactly did you change that triggered this to start happening?

Comment: YAAA! I found my mistake jaja
Days ago I have a problem with my website and it was down. And I active the wordpress debug, so i have this in my wp-config: define('WP_DEBUG', true); and  
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);. I just eliminate this last and place define('WP_DEBUG', false); and the message dissapear :D

Comment: So i can think eveything is okay now...!

Comment: Those warnings still happen even if you turn `WP_DEBUG` off, you haven't fixed the problem, it's just hidden now, it's still worth tracking the issue down and fixing it

Comment: I am going to delete my error file and watch if the error appear again there

Answer (score 1):

The root problem here is assumptions.

For example lets say we have an array here:

```php
$test = [
    'foo' => 'bar'
];
```

If we run `echo $test['foo'];` we should see *bar*, but what if we ran `echo $test['bananas'];`? There is no bananas entry in that array, so PHP will notice this, throw a warning/notice similar to the one you're seeing, then fill in the missing value with `''` or `null`.

This also happens with objects, e.g. if we take a classic post object and try to do this: `echo $post->odijfnvlkdsfnvlkjdsnvkljdfnv;`, we'll get a warning/notice

The same is true of your code. Most likely, the code calls an API but never checks if it was succesful, and just assumes it was. Or, a variable is misspelt.

You can check for these things with guards such as `if ( !empty( ... ) ) {`, or by checking return values on WP functions to see if they returned what you expected them to, or if something went wrong.

> What could be happen? I have made rollback but the message still appear. Is it dangerous?

Yes and no, there are possible consequences of this, and it depends a lot on what you're doing and how it could interact. Because you're assuming the values are good when they aren't, or using things that don't exist, PHP will substitute a placeholder value. That value is a `false`-ish value, and might mess up your logic, or lead to unexpected situations. That could be cryptic errors, or avenues to exploit security.

The biggest issue is when PHP is configured to show these warnings on the frontend, which can break REST XMLRPC and AJAX, as well as anything that changes HTTP headers to do things

The most annoying issue though, is that debugging with a PHP error log becomes almost impossible due to the huge numbers of warnings this would generate. Anything of interest becomes buried under a deluge of notices about object properties and array keys being access that don't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the big and clear explanation. And No, the message not appear in my interfaz.That's good for me...
Although I dont know if I should leave things like that. Or I could contact with my host to do roll-back. What do you say? I have unistalled the pluging that I installed, and delete the codes that I entered. But the message still appear

Answer (score 1):

The properties listed in your notices are all properties of the `$post` object.  The notices are indicating that where this is used, the `$post` object is not defined (i.e. it is not an existing object).

This can occur as a result of plugins/themes and/or a combination of those things, or custom code.  Based on your description ("I was moving something in my web to add a class to all my images"), what you are doing may be intending to use the `$post` object, but it is not actually defined where you are trying to use it.

This may be as simple as applying it as a "global" variable in your code (assuming this is a code snippet).  If so, try adding this:

```
global $post;
```

Or, provide some more detail on what you changed (and what you had before the change).

Answer (score 0):

If you see this happening in a function outside of a theme template, then adding `global $post;` to the top of the function *might* work.

If it's happening on a single theme template, first make sure that you're using the `$post` object after the `the_post()` function call.

It's also likely that you're trying to use the `$post` object on a page that doesn't have one. This could include search results, 404, archives, and any other scenario where a single $post object isn't generated. In these cases I avoid the issue by checking to see if the `$post` object is a valid instance of the `WP_Post` class:

```
is_a($post, 'WP_Post')
```

Here's a working example of where I'd typically use this approach:

```
/**
 * Hero Lead-in
 */
function hero_leadin() {
  global $post;

  // No $post object exists
  if ( ! is_a($post, 'WP_Post') ) return;
  
  return get_field('hero__lead-in');
}
```

If my theme's `header.php` uses this `hero_leadin()` function, it won't lead to the `trying to get property 'id' of non-object` PHP notice.